# MySQL using REGEXP causing long query times

Tags: mysql, regex

I understand that using REGEXP has its drawbacks, especially when it comes to query times, however, I have no other option, except to use it.

The problem is, queries can take over 5 minutes to run, depending on how many search terms are used.

My task is to take a search term, and find the exact search term, and some variations of the word, such as plural, ending in 'ing', or the search term followed by any punctuation, but NOT fragments of words, so "car" should not match "carbine" or "scar".
A infinite number of search terms can be used, but when the number starts to get above 6, it becomes unbearably long.

Here is a sample of my query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE (( 
    `name`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]sesame street[[:>:]]" OR
    `name`  REGEXP "sesame street[[:punct:]]" OR
    `name`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]sesame street.?ing[[:>:]]" OR
    `name`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]sesame street.?s[[:>:]]"
) OR ( 
    `venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney[[:>:]]" OR
    `venue`  REGEXP "disney[[:punct:]]" OR
    `venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney.?ing[[:>:]]" OR
    `venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney.?s[[:>:]]"
 )) 
 AND `name` NOT LIKE "% tantrum %" 
 AND `name` NOT LIKE "% stepkids %" 
 AND `date` >= CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY `date` ASC;
```

The query uses a single table, so there is no table join issues.

A single query could contain 30 different keywords that could be either to include, or exclude, and then there are the variations of those search terms, so each term could create 5 different conditionals.
Since the query uses REGEXP, the only index that can be used is the `date` field, although indexes are set up on the `name` and `venue` field. 
I have thought about changing my search engine to use something like Solr instead, but even then, i do not think it will work, given the specificity that the search requires.

Any advice is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve some improvement (up to factor of 4) by using a single expression per search term instead of the four you have now.

Instead of using:

```
`venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney[[:>:]]" OR
`venue`  REGEXP "disney[[:punct:]]" OR
`venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney.?ing[[:>:]]" OR
`venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney.?s[[:>:]]"
```

You could write:

```
`venue`  REGEXP "[[:<:]]disney(.?(s|ing))?[[:>:]]"
```

You don't need `"disney[[:punct:]]"` as `[[:>:]]` will match between words and punctuation.